# Removing Paw backups

Tags: macos, installation, paw-app

Every time i update Paw (API tool for mac) the installer backups the old application.

When i use the spotlight search to open paw it offers me various available versions. And of course i just want to open the latest version of paw.

Searching for the installed paw applications gives me the following output:

```
x@y:~$ system_profiler -detailLevel full SPApplicationsDataType | grep Paw
Paw:
  Location: /Applications/Paw.app
Paw:
  Location: /Users/x/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/Paw/Paw 3000016002/Paw.app
Paw:
  Location: /Users/x/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/Paw/Paw 3001002003/Paw.app
Paw:
  Location: /Users/x/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/Paw/Paw 3001001001 1/Paw.app
Paw:
  Location: /Users/x/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/Paw/Paw 3001001001/Paw.app
```

Should i just remove the `Application Support/Paw` folder?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes you can safely remove the folder: `~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/Paw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely delete the folder:

`~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/Paw`

Though, please note that this other folder contains import caches, licensing infos, and response/cookie history. **Do not delete it!**

`~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/com.luckymarmot.Paw`